# AngularJS factory promises and PouchDB

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, pouchdb

I have written the following service that get data from a local json file:

```
healthSystemService.factory('HealthSystemData', ['$resource',
function($resource) {
  return $resource('scripts/data/health-system/data.json', {}, {
    get: {
      method: 'GET',
      isArray: true
    }
  });
}
]);
```

Then I use this service in my controllers:

```
$scope.healthSystems = HealthSystemData.get();
```

Now, I know how to fetch the same data from a pouchDB database:

```
var db = new PouchDB('healthsystems');

db.get('healthsystems_list').then(function(doc) {
    return doc.list;
});
```

As you can see it is a promise that I resolve with a .then

My problem is when I try to replace my hard coded data in my factory

```
'scripts/data/health-system/data.json'
```

with the data from the couchDB. What I am trying to do is something like:

```
healthSystemService.factory('HealthSystemData', ['$resource',
function($resource) {
  return $resource(***DATA FROM THE COUCHDB(a promise)***, {}, {
    get: {
      method: 'GET',
      isArray: true
    }
  });
}
```

I do not quite understand how to use promises in services factory. Could you please help with some code?

Comment: You are not trying to fetch the data from pouchdb, just the url of the json file that contains the data. Is that what you inted to do? If not, then $resource should no longer be the prototype of your factory.

Comment: Hi kroonwijk, thank you for your reply. If I understand properly I need to rewrite my service.factory to include the code  db.get('healthsystems_list').then(function(doc) {
    return doc.list;
}); that return a promise and use it in my controller. Have you got an example I can follow?

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS resources have some tricky finagling in them that allows you to use them without dealing with the promises inside, but most promises are not like that.

So in your case, you should have your service return a promise:

```
healthSystemService.factory('HealthSystemData', ['$q',
    function($q) {
        var db = new PouchDB('healthsystems');

        // use $q.resolve to wrap the PouchDB promise in an Angular promise
        return $q.resolve(db.get('healthsystems_list')).then(function(doc) {
            return doc.list;
        });
    }
]);
```

Then use `.then()` within your controller to get the data out of it:

```
HealthySystemData.then(function (data) {
    $scope.healthSystems = data;
});
```